# last row of uicollectionview is not visible while scrolling

Tags: scroll, collectionview

I created UiCollectionView programmatically. This is my code snippet...

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    collectionV=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500) collectionViewLayout:layout];

```
[collectionV setDataSource:self];
[collectionV setDelegate:self];
[collectionV registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
[collectionV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
collectionV.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

[self.view addSubView:CollectionV];

My problem is I could not see the last row while scrolling. Anybody help me to fix it.
Thanks in advance.